# Ubuntu can't see the D: windows partition

Tags: mount, partitioning

I have installed ubuntu in my laptop and everything was going well, but I had a problem that ubuntu's file manager can't see the windows D: partition.

Here is some photos of the problem:

in the left side I can just see the OS partition which is C:
[image]

I think that ubuntu sees the D: partition because it is the /dev/sda5:
[image]

What shall I do to access my Windows' D: partition?

Comment: According to your `df` output, `/dev/sda5` is mounted at `/windows`: have you tried browsing there (`Computer` --> `windows`)?

Comment: Yes of course. I could enter to the D: partition from windows

Comment: I think you don't realize that  `/windows` is actually a folder, and your partition is linked to a folder.

Comment: You now have 3 answers, please consider accepting the one of them that helped you most to solve your problem by clicking the grey round tick symbol on the left of it. In case none did really help you yet, please reply and tell what's still wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of this command: `sudo blkid`

Answer (score 1):

Your partition D is mounted on /windows :

```
cd /windows && ls -lA
```

If you have issue with the mountpoint, show us the line of your `/etc/fstab` which mounted the `/dev/sda5`:

```
grep -A1 "/dev/sda5" /etc/fstab
```

Maybe you just need to install the NTFS support on your distribution:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: My issue that I want to enter to the D: partition from ubuntu's file manager.

root@anas-X555LAB:/windows# cat /etc/fstab | grep /dev/sda5
# /windows was on /dev/sda5 during installation

Comment: Ubuntu makes the fstab entries using UUIDs, not using the /dev/sdXY name. Therefore you should use this command to search for it: `grep -A1 "/dev/sda5" /etc/fstab` - I edited your answer.

Comment: root@anas-X555LAB:~# grep -A1 "/dev/sda5" /etc/fstab
# /windows was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=CE5425685425548D /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0

Comment: the  UUID is CE5425685425548D. What should I do now!!

Comment: And ? What is the issue . Go on your file manager in Computer > Windows ... Your screen shows nothing!

Comment: :`( I want to enter to D: Partition from ubuntu file manager not from Windows

Comment: In windows everything is OK!!!!!

Comment: And what is the error ... ?! Go on your filemanager in Computer > windows to go in /windows ...

Answer (score 1):

The partition that Windows calls `D:` (`sda5` on your Ubuntu installation) gets automatically mounted on every boot by your Ubuntu.

But as Ubuntu uses a different way to represent your devices and file system structures than Windows, you can't access partitions through their assigned device letter, but you can see the raw partition as file (`/dev/sda5`) and mount it to a mountpoint (any directory in your directory tree) to be able to access its contents there.

You have an entry for it in your `/etc/fstab` configuration file which mounts `/dev/sda5` (your Windows' D: partition) to the mountpoint `/windows` (`windows` directory directly in your file system root directory `/`).

From the terminal, you can change your working directory to this partition's root directory by simply navigating there:

```
cd /windows
```

Using your graphical file manager Nautilus, you can go there by first navigating to your file system root directory `/` (using the <kbd>Computer</kbd> button from the **Devices** list in the left sidebar) and then going to the `windows` directory from there.

If you want to access your D: partition directly through the sidebar of Nautilus, you can create a bookmark for it. Navigate to the `/windows` folder as described above in your file manager and then click in the **Bookmarks** menu on **Bookmark this location** - or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. A new entry in the sidebar will appear, called "windows". You can rename it by right-clicking on it and selecting **Rename** from the context menu.

Comment: Just for clarity, I am not talking about Windows in this answer at any point. All actions and observations are to be done from Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Go to disk utility and mount all those partitions (D: in your case).

If you had win 8 or more installed in your computer previously, then use

> sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdX

where X is your drive

Comment: Didn't work, Terminal says :Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda5.
@Vedant

Comment: There's no need to try fixing any NTFS errors yet, as we have no evidence there might be anything wrong with it.